# В какой папке создавать servlet в maven проектах разве не в java?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, servlet

В какой папке создавать servlet в maven проектах разве не в java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё верно, создавайте в папке java.

Comment: добавьте в ответ, что главное, это не забыть замапить его в web.xml

Comment: @DaysLikeTHis кто вам такую глупость сказал?

Comment: Я новичок и вот думаю почему не делать как требует система но вдруг нет java папки. Чем это чревато, будет ли себя хорошо вести при этом IDE в дальнейшей работе? Спасибо!

Comment: @DaysLikeThis мой ответ ровно такой каким должен быть, под стать вопросу. Он был бы ещё короче, просто "Да", но SO не позволяет.

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал новичку сначала собирать всё руками, чтобы лучше разобраться. А вот когда скомпилированный и упакованный из командной строки сервлет нормально будет работать на руками же запущенном сервере, тогда браться за сборщики и IDE.

Comment: Сергей, такая практика имеется, но как я понимаю maven  это не просто сборщик но и строгая структура?! вот и вошел в ступор. А вот эклипс не дает создать сервлет в папке java (Not a Java source folder)

Comment: Хотя в http://www.apache-maven.ru/webapp.html пишут что можно:

Answer (score 1):

Все разобрался. Можно только в DWP версии 3.1. В eclipse  в project facets надо изменить версию. и в web.xml конечно же

Всем спасибо за реакцию.